# variable declaration in function return type specifier c++type

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-extensions

I was trying out codefights.com and noticed someones answer to a question which involved giving all the longest strings in a vector do this:

```
std::vector<std::string> r, allLongestStrings(std::vector<std::string> a) {
    int b=0;
    for (s:a) if (s.size()>b) b=s.size();
    for (s:a) if (s.size()==b) r.push_back(s);
    return r;
}
```

He's declaring a variable in the return type specifier for the function, can anyone tell me why this is allowed? I't doesn't compile on my machine and I couldn't find a gcc extension that does this, thanks in advance :).

Comment: Are you sure that the solution works? As written, this does not appear to be valid C++.

Comment: Not valid C++ in any way. This form of the ranged-for was allowed by certain version of GCC, but was removed later as the standard forbid it. As for declaring a variable in the return type... What?

Comment: I know!, the for loops also confused me but it works on the codefights website and passes all the tests :S

Comment: I would say the intent is `std::vector<std::string> r;  std::vector<std::string> allLongestStrings(......);`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Function_definition) (*decl-specifier-seq*), I don't see how it would be possible to declare the return variable before the function name.

With C++14, you can use the `auto` keyword to remove the duplicate mentioning of the return type:

```
auto allLongestStrings( const std::vector<std::string>& a ) {
    std::vector<std::string> r;
    std::size_t b = 0;
    for( const auto& s : a ) if( s.size() > b ) b = s.size();
    for( const auto& s : a ) if( s.size() == b ) r.push_back( s );
    return r;
}
```

I fixed some other things of the code:

- to improve efficiency, declare the parameter `a` as const reference, so it won't be copied
- declare `b` as `std::size_t` to match return type of `std::vector::size()`
- in range-for loop, a type specifier is necessary (even if it is `auto`); added const reference for efficiency

[Live demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2be3ac57401c5ead)

Comment: I think, that's a comma operator there and is an exploit of test unit's code <.<;

Answer (score 0):

The mixed variable / function declaration seems to be ok, though gcc complains that function definition shouldn't be there but I think it's ok at global scope. But it's a 100% valid syntax even in non-global scope if no function definition is given. This declaration is just regular declarations of several items of the same leading type. For example we can declare multiple items of different kinds but with same leading like this:

```
// single line declaration
int i = 0, * p_i = nullptr, ai[2] = {42,42}, geti(void), * * getppi(void);
// the same as
int i = 0;
int * p_i = nullptr;
int ai[2] = {42, 42};
int geti(void);
int ** getppi(void);
```

So `r` is just a regular variable of type `std::vector<std::string>`, followed by function allLongestStrings that returns the same std::vector type.

This compact declaration form exists for historical reasons. Basically it helped to save quite some bytes for storing and compiling the source file.

This form of `for` loop is probably on of the earlier experimental extensions before current form was standardized.

Comment: Your example shows mixing variable declarations with function declarations. OP's code is mixing a variable declaration with a function definition, which is not the same thing, and is not allowed.

Comment: no it's not ok in global scope.. i'm trying to figure what wrapper they use, but fail, at leat all modern compilers will through  error on any attempt to combine variable declaration and function definition via comma... either they have very dated or exotic compiler and and their wrapper is some kind of  template in which answer gets pasted or something really weird is happening there

Comment: [IntelCC seems to allow](https://godbolt.org/g/7JERJT) putting function definition in global scope after variable like in OP's example.

Comment: Then that may be what they use, but it isn't standard compliant as your answer claims.

Comment: @interjay My answer doesn't claim anything like this, I explicitly state that it is ok to mix variable declarations with function declarations only when no definition is given. Please consider rereading my answer before writing negative comments.

Comment: You answer seems to say that the code in the question should be allowed (e.g. "gcc complains that function definition shouldn't be there but I think it's ok at global scope"). In any case, the question wasn't about mixing declarations, so I don't see how this answers the question if you are only talking about that.

Comment: It actually tells "I think it's ok at global scope", nothing like "it's standard".

Comment: I don't see any meaningful way to interpret "I think it's ok" other than "it's standard".

Comment: Well, if I was Stroustrup then maybe whatever I though would eventually mean "it's standard". But since I'm not him I'm using phrases such as "i'm thinking" to express my opinion. And as for these one-line declarations I think that they are just an abominations of old times and should not be used today at all.

Comment: This website is not about opinions but about facts. Posting an incorrect fact and calling it an opinion doesn't make it fine. And even as an opinion, I don't see what you mean by "it's ok".

Comment: By "it's ok" I mean that since language allows putting new struct/class definition in variable declaration then it would make sense for putting a new function definition in variable declaration to be allowed as well (at least at global scope). Also I don't get your point in claiming that "This website is not about opinions but about facts" and pushing this rather pointless and clearly opinion-based discussion at the same time.

Comment: Look, you posted an incorrect answer. That's not an opinion but a fact. And instead of deleting it you just keep arguing. I'll stop commenting now because it's pointless to argue with someone who is incapable of admitting mistakes.

Comment: I've posted a rather correct answer. Your complaint "no it's not ok in global scope" only refers to the first sentence and is clearly invalidated by the fact that Intel compiler devs actually implemented described approach as a valid language construct. Which seems to answers OP's question "why this is allowed?".